# SwingUtilities invokeLater equivalent in SWT / Eclipse 3.x API?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, long-running-processes

What is [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) equivalent in Eclipse API 3.x?

I.e. how to run something on "main thread"?

Can I use

```
@Inject 
UISynchronize sync;
```

for this in Eclipse Plug-In 3.x?

It is written, that [`UISynchronize`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/e4/ui/di/UISynchronize.html) is valid "since 1.0". What does it mean? Why is it in `e4` package then?

Comment: whatever defines a notion of "main thread"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use `@Inject` simply on Eclipse 4.x application model objects (the Eclipse 4.x API is known as `e4`). So unless you do extra work you can't use injection in the Eclipse 3.x API.

More recent versions of Eclipse do support views declared using the `e4view` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point. These can make use of `@Inject`.

`Display.getDefault().asyncExec()` is used with `SWT` objects to run code in the `SWT` main thread.

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
     .. code to update the UI
  }
});
```

Comment: Always very helpful content from your side!